# Taxi service at Chennai airport

Tags: india, taxis, pre-pay, chennai, maa

Can anyone tell me where the prepaid taxi counter in the Chennai airport is? Is it inside or outside the airport building?

According to the internet, multiple prepaid taxi counters are present. Which one to go to for taxi? Which will be safer? I am a female travelling alone. My flight lands at 10:45 in the morning in the domestic terminal. I will have luggage with me and I need to be dropped exactly at my destination point. Any taxi service that would not abandon midway and also safe? I really need these info.

Comment: International or domestic flight?  There are two terminals.

Comment: Also, there's a train station right next to the airport which you can use to get into town.

Comment: I'll check it out on my visit there shortly. But in the meanwhile have you considered using Uber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find taxi counters just as you come out of airport. Some even have outlets inside airport. Or you can book a cab through ola/meru/taxiforsure, they will pick you up from airport.

Answer (score 1):

There are only three types of taxis which are allowed to take passengers in Chennai Airport as far as I know.  All of them are expensive, but none of them are particularly unsafe.  Fast track is a service I have personally used and found to be safe.  Since the standard mode of saving money, a.k.a Rickshaws are not allowed (and arent particularly better at safety), you may choose to go with one of them.

http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/chennai/passengers-at-airport-taken-for-a-ride/article3426363.ece  gives details of the issues, the last time I checked (which was after this article) the conditions were similar.